# debian 10 + Display USB-C

Tags: linux, debian, external-display, usb-c

I am trying to make it work an display connected through a [docking](https://www.visiontek.com/dual-4k-usb-dock.html) hub (usb-c).

looks like something is detected

```
lsusb 
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 17e9:6000 DisplayLink 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04e8:1f05 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd S2 Portable [JMicron] (500GB)
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:24a1 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e300 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6713 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

but doesn't show up in settings -> displays

using Debian 10 with Kenel 4.19 ... in theory this kernel support it.

Any clue ?

Regarding Graphic card

```
# nvidia-detect 
Detected NVIDIA GPUs:
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [10de:1c8d] (rev a1)

Checking card:  NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
Your card is supported by the default drivers and legacy driver series 390.
```

Comment: DisplayLink requires drivers.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I had nvidia-driver installed ... what else is it need it ?

Comment: The DisplayLink drivers, nothing to do with Nvidia's. https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

Comment: I am using debian, not ubuntu

Comment: Yes, I've read your question. Those are the drivers published by the manufacturer. If they don't work in Debian I'm afraid you'll have to find alternatives. At least now you know what's needed.